# Building single qt module out of source in Qt 5

Tags: c++, build, qt5, nmake

I use Qt 5.5.1, C++, Visual Studio 2013 compiler. I had to build Qt from sources (shadow build mode). But I found later that one module qttools was skipped due to -skip flag. I am aware about `nmake module-qttools` command, but what is the full instruction concerning additional build (I failed with it)? I mean: should I call configure and what are the params? Where should I call `nmake module-qttools` (build/source directory)? Is it possible to clean *.obj files before `nmake install`?

BTW, where can I find exact module names? For example, here is the [module list](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmodules.html). But I can't just use `-skip "Qt Multimedia"` literally (for example).

Comment: Also trying to find a list of modules to skip. This is what I have figured out by guessing: -skip qtsensors -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtgamepad -skip qtlocation -skip qtwebengine

Comment: `ls $QTBASE/Src` to see all the modules.